# Asked for interview but told to meet with employee

Tags: job-search

In hopes of landing a job at a financial firm I really want to work for, I cold emailed a managing partner at their office in my city. He agreed to meet me for coffee, and we had a great 30 minute chat. Afterwards, he informed me that he was not hiring at his local office, but they were in another city with a bigger office. This worked out good for me, as I was planning on moving to this city anyways (and told him that) if I didn't land anything here as there are far more opportunities there.

He referred me to the hiring/managing partner at that city and told me to email him. I did, saying I was planning on visiting the city and it would be great to get to meet with him. The next day he replied to me the next day thanking me for emailing him and telling me to contact his "colleague when in town for a potential meetup".

I looked up this colleague to find that he is not a partner, but an employee with a similar job of what I am looking for.

Does this sound like something that may lead to a job, or is it just a curtesy reply since this employee would have been in a similar situation a year or two ago?

Comment: It's not uncommon for seemingly junior people to do the first round of interviews before passing you on to someone higher up. But did you actually ask for an interview? It reads like you just asked to meet the hiring director for a networking type chat. Whether it may lead to a job? I don't think we can say. However there's almost no downside to turning up and impressing the employee, then trying to take it from there.

Comment: @Rup I asked him to (in verbatim) "meet about working at Company X". You're right, no downside; other than the fact I'm travelling 7 hrs by plane to get there, but will be pursuing other opportunities

Comment: Seems like you'd be meeting with someone who's doing the same job you would be. Benefits for everybody: you can see what/who you'll actually have/get to do/work with, they get someone familiar with the role to eyeball your suitability for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like both a courtesy reply AND a job lead. This kind of networking is very good; You're getting direct encounters with industry people and time to impress. Are you going to get your next job out of it? Maybe not, and you need to pursue other opportunities. But it's an avenue worth your time investigating at the very least.

Send an email and gauge their enthusiasm to meet. From there you can determine the validity of the lead.